# to do or for doing

Tags: verbs, gerunds

Which sentence is correct grammatically?

> I am ready for watching TV
>
> I am ready to watch TV

In general, when we can replace to do with for doing in English?
It seems that both of them have an equal meaning.

Answer (score 1):

"to" implies a transfer so "I am ready to watch TV" implies a transfer from a state of not being ready to a state of being ready.

"for" implies that something is being done to benefit something or someone else. E.g.,"she runs for her health". It is hard to see how your watching TV would benefit something or someone else but it would depend on context.  If you are watching TV to see a friend compete in a contest then your watching could be said to benefit that person so for might be appropriate.

Comment: Dear Mr Ramsey, thank you so much, what about this sentence "the most important part for learning knowledge is students themselves" or "the most important part to learn knowledge is students themselves".

Comment: I don’t think I can agree with this.  I am ready for skiing. I am ready for dessert.  I am ready for my trip.  All are idiomatic, all mean that the necessary preparations have been made for the mentioned activity and none are being done for anyone else’s benefit.

Comment: @Jim Why are you ready for skiing? Because of the anticipation of the thrill and excitement of skiing the bumps?  If you only mean that you have completed all preparations than you are ready to ski. Think about it.

Comment: @Ahmad I am not sure that either is completely correct. "for learning" implies a benefit. "is students themselves" doesn't explicitly state a benefit. "to learn" implies a transition. Again, "is students themselves" doesn't describe a transition.

Comment: @MikeJRamsey56 - I am ready for skiing because I brought my skis and boots with me to the cabin.  I am not ready to ski because I haven’t put them on yet.

Comment: @Jim Then I am very happy for you. :-)